# PhpWord - TemplateProcessor: error copy template

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have developed a Laravel app that read a .docx template, populate and save it in pdf format.
On my pc and some server it works greatly, but with a new Debian 9 VPS I have a strange error. When I create the template (the PhpWord code try to copy my template from /var/www/myapp/... to /tmp/ ), I have this error:

```
copy(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

This it the line in TemplateProcessor.php that trow the exception:

```
if (false === copy($documentTemplate, $this->tempDocumentFilename)) {
            throw new CopyFileException($documentTemplate, $this->tempDocumentFilename);
}
```

Can you help me? I have a Debian 9 VPS, Nginx and PHP 7.2. 
Thanks!

Comment: What are the values for `$documentTemplate` and `$this->tempDocumentFilename`?

Comment: The first is the complete path of my template (that exists), the second is the file in /tmp with a random name. The file is created but with a dimension of 0b.

Comment: Looks like it may think that the `$documentTemplate` is a URL instead of a local path?

Comment: Thanks! In the other servers the URL works because the URL exists. In that case the URL is only in my hosts file...